# Passar valor de href jquery para Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

Boa tarde pessoal, estou com dificuldade em passar um id que está no href do jquery para método update do controller do Spring MVC.
Alguém poderia me ajudar.
Obrigado.

```
$.ajax({
        url : "listAllForum",
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(index, objeto) {
                $('#post-forum').last().append('<div class="jumbotron"> <strong>Nome do usuário que postou a mensagem!!!</strong> - ' 
                        +' Data: <br>' + objeto.message + '<br> <br>'
                        + '<input type="text" size="90" placeholder="Redigir uma resposta" id="answer" name="answer" />'
                        + ' <br> <br> <a href='**/update/**' + objeto.idForum + '>Responder</a> </div>');
                });
        }
    });
```

Quando cliclo em Responder, ao invés de chamar o método do controller, ele chama uma página update.